# Post data to restful api

Tags: c#

I have this method to post data to our company live rest service. It runs well without an error, but the data is not being posted to the server.

```
public void PostData()
{
   string sName = sysName.Text;
   string sDescrip = sysDescrip.Text;
   var httpclient = new HttpClient();
   httpclient.BaseAddress = new    Uri("http://88.209.233.99:8123/companayname/sysconfig/api/");
   var sys = new Bizsys(){name= sName, description= sDescrip};
   httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("system", sys);
}
```

Comment: it's really unclear. How you know that it's not posted?

Comment: I checked via the get method and the data I submitted was not among the ones there. We can also check the server with Swagger

Comment: Capture the result of your post with var result = httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("system", sys);  then you can access the status code of your post with result.StatusCode to see if you are getting a 200 (or you can use reuslt.IsSuccessStatusCode which is a bool), if not 200 or success you need to work through the issues with your request by viewing the result.reasonphrase or result.content.

Comment: try to monitor traffic between you'r app and server (fiddler, devtools), maybe you'll see what is going wrong